# Are there any third-party sources for compiled packages?

Tags: software-installation

[My previous question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/1007/package-browser-to-search-for-compiled-software-pre-install) does a good job of explaining how to find software from official sources.

What about third-party sources?  Are there any sites that have specialized in providing compiled software packages for the Raspberry Pi outside of the official repositories?

Comment: Why would you need such a repository?

Comment: I like software.  Just because it's not in an official repo doesn't mean that I don't want to install it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can install third party packages easily in Arch Linux. However, the packages are not pre-compiled, but are *known to compile*.

The third party packages are organised in the **Arch User Repository** (AUR) and can be utilised using `yaourt`. You can find more information about the AUR and yaourt [in this question](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/524/40).

One thing to note is that packages in the AUR are usually only for `x86_64` or `i686` architectures, but you can manually edit the package files during installation and add the `arm` flag instead, and most build fine.

You can browse the AUR in your web browser [here](http://aur.archlinux.org/).

Comment: AUR packages aren't compiled, rather known to compile.

Comment: Oh right, the question said `compiled`. I will amend my answer.